# Plot multiple small line graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have some data where I have deaths each year across each state. I am attempting to make several small line graphs (sort of like what's demonstrated [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/125-small-multiples-for-line-chart/)), however, I cannot get my data to go the way it seems to need to go to make this.

Without attempting this method, I attempted `df.pivot(index="fyear", columns="state_abbr", values="total_deaths").plot()` which of course just put 50 lines on one graph...not a great look.

How do I get individual line graphs for each state in a neat, organized way? (well, as neat as you can get with 50 graphs)

**Sample Data**

```
data = {'state_abbr':['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AL', 'AK', 'AZ',], 
        'fyear':[2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016],
        'total_deaths':[500, 490, 510, 530, 480, 510, 600, 400, 230]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use seaborn's FacetGrid for this:

```
# sns style, looks like those in your picture
sns.set()

# play with `col_wrap`
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='state_abbr', col_wrap=5)
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'fyear', 'total_deaths')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How would you write the result to a file?

Comment: @four-eyes from [the documentations](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html): `g.savefig("facet_plot.png")`

Comment: Thanks, I referenced the old API, with `save_fig()`.